# How to add Instagram Follow button in my website?

Tags: javascript, html, instagram, social-networking

I am able to add the follow button for twitter, subscribe button for youtube and "like" button for facebook, Is is possible to code the follow button for our Instagram account in the website?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/shmdhussain/jtcz2jtz/2/[image]

```html
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>

<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="GoogleDevelopers" data-layout="default" data-count="default"></div>

<script>window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    t = window.twttr || {};
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 
  t._e = [];
  t.ready = function(f) {
    t._e.push(f);
  };
 
  return t;
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));</script>

<a class="twitter-follow-button"   href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev" data-show-screen-name="false" data-lang="ar"> Follow @TwitterDev</a>
```

Answer (score 9):

Add this fontawesome link tag to your HTML head

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
```

Then put this code where you want to show the Instagram button and change the username to yours

```
<a href="https://instagram.com/username">
   <span style="font-size: 1.5rem;">
       <span style="color: indianred;">
          <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
       </span>
   </span>
</a>
```

Comment: In a way I like the originality to this... "just link to IG"

Comment: @JamieHutber thanks. You can vote for my answer to show it's useful.

Comment: very nice solution.